# mkdir command for a list of filenames paths

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have txt file with content like this

```
/home/username/Desktop/folder/folder3333/IMAGw488.jpg
/home/username/Desktop/folder/folder3333/IMAG04f88.jpg
/home/username/Desktop/folder/folder3333/IMAGe0488.jpg
/home/username/Desktop/folder/folder3333/IMAG0r88.jpg
/home/username/Desktop/folder/folder3333/
/home/username/Desktop/folder/
/home/username/Desktop/folder/IMAG0488.jpg
/home/username/Desktop/folder/fff/fff/feqw/123.jpg
/home/username/Desktop/folder/fffa/asd.png
....
```

these are filenames paths but also paths of folders.
The problem I want to solve is to create all folders that doesn't exist.

I want to call mkdir command for every folder that does not exist

How can I do this on easy way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done in native `bash` syntax without any calls to external binaries:

```
while read line; do mkdir -p "${line%/*}"; done < infile
```

Or perhaps with a just a single call to `mkdir` if you have `bash 4.x`

```
mapfile -t arr < infile; mkdir -p "${arr[@]%/*}"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
xargs -n 1 dirname <somefile.txt | xargs mkdir -p
```

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
for p in $(xargs < somefile.txt);
do
    mkdir -p $(dirname ${p})
done
```

Comment: There are some nicer ways to handle this problem, `bash` has very mature facilities for file handling, but this is nice and short.

Comment: `xargs` is certainly unnecessary. `while read p <somefile.txt; do ...`

Comment: ... Or you could `sed 's%[^/]*$%%' somefile.txt | xargs mkdir -p`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without loop also (provided input file not huge):

```
mkdir -p $(perl -pe 's#/(?!.*/).*$##' file.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have file "file1" with filenames you could try this oneliner:

```
cat file1 |xargs -I {} dirname "{}"| sort -u | xargs -I{} mkdir -p "{}"
```

Use of:

```
xargs -I{} mkdir -p "{}"
```

ensures that even path names with spaces will be created

Answer (score 0):

Using a perl one-liner and [`File::Path qw(make_path)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html):

```
perl -MFile::Path=make_path -lne 'make_path $_' dirlist.txt
```